# Grant public access to one GAE servlet but use authentication for all other resources?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, servlets

for an online bug report web application, I need to find a way how any user can submit a bug report (using HTTP POST) to a Servlet in a Google App Engine application, while all other Servlets (the application admin interface) are protected so that they grant access only to users which have logged in with their [Google account](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html#Security_and_Authentication). The application runs at /* and if this URL is secured using Google Accounts, no servlet will be available without authentication and there seems to be no way to exclude a URL from authentication.

So this should be protected:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

While this should be public:

```
<url-pattern>/addbugreport</url-pattern>
```

- just an idea for a workaround: all servlets in the application (except the public one) could check if a user has logged on (and forward to a login page if not logged in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If url-patterns are more important than declarative security; implement the user-check as a servlet `Filter` (mapped to `'/*'`). This will, in a clean way, separate security from request-handling logic.

Answer (score 1):

Put the protected resources in a different context (directory) from the public (using `servlet-mapping`'s in web.xml). If the public resources are in `'/'`, put the protected in `'/admin'` and define a `security-contraint` (also in web.xml) for that context only.

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>admin resources</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>*</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

If you add more protected contexts to the application, you need to define security-contraints for them as well.

Comment: See my edit, actually I want to keep the protected admin interface at / and put the public available servlet at /newbugreport - but maybe it is only possible to drop this plan and follow your your suggestion, so +1

Comment: If url-patterns are more important than declarative security; implement the user-check as a servlet Filter (mapped to '/*'). This will, in a clean way, separate security from request-handling logic.

Comment: Good idea - it is a Wicket application, so it is a filter already and adding some security logic code to it should be easy. Could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?